# How can I convert this dictionary into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'NorthernRegion': {'date': '2021-12-31',
'state': PA,
'candySales': 500,
'grocerySales': 1500,
'electronicSales': 800,
...
   },
{'date': '2021-12-30',
 ...
   },
{'date': '2021-12-29',
 ...
   },
...
}
```

It is a nested dictionary. I want the nested dictionary to make up a Pandas data frame. For example, each row would be a date, and the other categories would make up the columns. What is the best way to go about this? I don't seem to be making any quality progress.

The data frame would look like

```
Date       State     Candy Sales   Grocery Sales  ...
-------------------------------------------------------
2021-12-31  PA       500           1500           ...
2021-12-30  PA       600           1600           ...
...
```

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* (but complete) reproducible example, with input and expected output. Also show us what you tried

Comment: The input is shown above. I just added the output @RiccardoBucco

Comment: Is your input reproducible and minimal? Are you sure? How can I use it in my own env? How does your output relate to the input? The output contains data that can't even be found in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each dictionary item needs a key and value, so assuming the complete structure of your dictionary looks something like the following:

```
sample_dict = {'NorthernRegion': {'date': '2021-12-31',
'state': 'PA',
'candySales': 500,
'grocerySales': 1500,
'electronicSales': 800},
'SouthernRegion':{'date': '2021-12-31',
'state': 'PA',
'candySales': 500,
'grocerySales': 1500,
'electronicSales': 800}}
```

To get the inner dictionaries as columns as the outer keys as index values, you can try `pd.DataFrame(sample_dict).T` which will result in the following DataFrame:

```
                      date state candySales grocerySales electronicSales
NorthernRegion  2021-12-31    PA        500         1500             800
SouthernRegion  2021-12-31    PA        500         1500             800
```